# Tanto en windows 10 como en windows 11, la captura de imagenes de la cámara USB es en negro. He probado distintos modos de captura del DSHOW

Tags: python-3.x, cv2

Cuando intento adquirir imágenes desde python3 bien sea con OpenCV o imageio, puedo acceder a la cámara, tengo validación de grab, pero la imagen es negra. Sin embarco con cualquier aplicación de escritorio sí que muestra vídeo. ¿A qué puede ser debido?

Ejemplo del códio probado:

```
        import cv2

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW);
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
        out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

        while True: 
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            try:
                cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
                out.write(frame)

            except:
                print ('ERROR - Not writting to file')

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

        cap.release()
        out.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```